# Will these two MDX queries return identical results?

Tags: sql-server, mdx, business-intelligence

Will these two MDX queries provide identical result?
GeoDim is a hierarchy: Country->Region->City

`[GeoDim].[City].[London].Parent.Parent.Children`
and
`[GeoDim].[Region].Members`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one country then yes they return the same regions. If you have more than one country then .Children will return just regions in the UK but .Members will return regions from all countries.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation!